# How to "accumulate" a tab in function in JS

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a tab that I want to use in a function

```js
const extractLinks = async (url, arrLinks) => {
// do things on arrLinks
return arrLinks;
}
```

I want to create a tab in the beginning of my program, and call several time the function extractLinks on the same tab, to have one tab with lot of values :

```js
let arrLinks = []; // New tab
for (let cptpages = 1; cptpages < 33; cptpages++) { 
  const URL = 'https://droidsoft.fr/category/tests-android/page/' + cptpages;
  extractLinks(URL, arrLinks);
}
```

When I do that, if I put a console.log(arrLinks), in the function, it prints the value, but after the for iteration, the tab is clear.

Could you help me ?

My whole code :

```js
// Kindacode.com
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const got = (...args) => import('got').then(({ default: got }) => got(...args));
// You cannot use "require" with the latest version of got
// If you're using ES Module or TypeScript, just import got like this: import got from 'got'

const extractLinks = async (url, arrLinks) => {
  try {
    // Fetching HTML
    const response = await got(url);
    const html = response.body;

    // Using cheerio to extract <a> tags
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);

    const linkObjects = $('a');
    // this is a mass object, not an array

    // Collect the "href" and "title" of each link and add them to an array
    const links = [];
    linkObjects.each((index, element) => {
      if ($(element).attr('href').startsWith('https://droidsoft.fr/202') && $(element).attr('href').includes('test-')) {
        links.push($(element).attr('href'));
      }
    });
    arrLinks = [...new Set(links)];  
    console.log(arrLinks);
    return arrLinks;
    // do something else here with these links, such as writing to a file or saving them to your database
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

// Try it
let arrLinks = []; // Tableau vide à la base
for (let cptpages = 1; cptpages < 33; cptpages++) { // On parcourt les 33 pages de tests-android
  const URL = 'https://droidsoft.fr/category/tests-android/page/' + cptpages;
  extractLinks(URL, arrLinks); // On appelle la fonction pour récuperer les URL de chaque test, de chaque page, avec le tableau initial
}

console.log(arrLinks);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're re assigning `arrLinks` everytime, as seen toward the bottom of the code snippet as: `arrLinks = [...new Set(links)];`

Instead you'll want to do one of the following:

- Array.prototype.push -> `arrLinks.push([...new Set(links)])`
- Clone, add, and set as new  -> `arrLinks = [...arrLinks, ...new Set(links)]`

Alternatively, you could go a different route entirely:

```
const extractLinks = async (url) => {
  try {
    // Fetching HTML
    const response = await got(url);
    const html = response.body;

    // Using cheerio to extract <a> tags
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);

    const linkObjects = $('a');
    // this is a mass object, not an array

    // Collect the "href" and "title" of each link and add them to an array
    const links = [];
    linkObjects.each((index, element) => {
      if ($(element).attr('href').startsWith('https://droidsoft.fr/202') && $(element).attr('href').includes('test-')) {
        links.push($(element).attr('href'));
      }
    });
    return links // return the array of links itself
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

// Try it
let arrLinks = []; // Tableau vide à la base
for (let cptpages = 1; cptpages < 33; cptpages++) { // On parcourt les 33 pages de tests-android
  const URL = 'https://droidsoft.fr/category/tests-android/page/' + cptpages;
  // now we're keeping the array each time and 
  // simply adding the results of the function to it
  arrLinks.push(await extractLinks(URL))  // may need to wrap loop in async func to use await
}
// If you want arrLinks to be a completely flat array 
// (since it will will be an array of arrays, you can just 
// call the `.flat()` method after you're finished like  so `arrLinks.flat()`
console.log(arrLinks);
```

Comment: First, thanks a lot for the answer !
I tried the two options of what you gave me, and it still doesn't work.
Can it be linked to the fact that it is an async operation, so that it isn't done at the end of the for loop ?

The code update with your solution :D
https://pastebin.com/heyFmTtG

Comment: @MicMac I've edited my answer and added a new solution, applicable to your code directly

Comment: I see the idea, but I got this issue now
`SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:15)`

And it is pointing to the await method